# React JS/react hook form handleSubmit inside of window event listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

```
import { FormProvider, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
```

...

```
  const { reset, handleSubmit } = methods
```

...

```
<BaseModal
  title='Update Quantity'
  open={open}
  closeHandler={onClose}
  closeButton
  dividers
  actions={[
    {text: 'Submit', action: handleSubmit(onSubmit), submit: true}
  ]}
>
  <FormProvider {...methods}>
    <Grid container spacing={FormSpacing}>
      {/*<Grid item xs={12}><InfoText text='Press enter or click submit to update the quantity' /></Grid>*/}
      <FormInputText name='id' label='id' hidden={true} />
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <FormInputNumber id='quantity-input' name='quantity' label='Quantity' min={1} selectOnFocus />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </FormProvider>
</BaseModal>
```

...
handleSubmit is called inside of a react material UI button:

```
<Button onClick={action.action()} ...>{action.text}</Button>
```

This works great, the form is submitted correctly. However when I try to allow a user to submit via pressing the enter key, handleSubmit is not called.

```
  useEffect(() => {

    ...
    
    const enterHandler = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      if (e.code === 'Enter' || e.code == 'NumpadEnter') {
        console.log('enterHandler')
        handleSubmit(
          (e: any, data: any) => console.log('data :', e, data),
          (e: any, data: any) => {
              console.log('invalid data :', e, data)
        })
      }
    }

    // allow polling for enter key press
    window.addEventListener('keydown', enterHandler, false)

    return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', enterHandler, false)
  }, [id])
```

The 'data' and 'invalid data' console logs are not seen in the console after pressing enter, however the console.log('enterHandler') is called:

```
enterHandler                             8   LineplanItemQuantityModal.tsx:47
```

I am not sure why submitHandler cannot be called inside this event listener, does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Comment: Are you doing this just so that `Enter` key defaults to submitting?, if so you don't even need to do this, just set the `Button` type to submit, and then use the `onSubmit` callback on the form.  This will then also work nicely for mobile etc.   IOW: don't handle submits on button clicks, use the Forms onSubmit.

Comment: I have it set to type submit to no avail.. I think my base form component doesn't make use of the <form> tag.

<button class="MuiButton-root ..." type="submit">Submit
<span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-8je8zh-MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>

Comment: That could be your problem, if you can I would look into placing your dialog into a form, that's how I have my dialogs, it then just works as expected,  especially if you also want it to work logically on mobile.  Don't use `react-hook-form` but looking at the docs it seems to want you to provide a `form` element.

Comment: Ah, that did it. I added a conditional form component with the onSubmit event in my basemodal and that submits the form on enter. Thanks for the help!